# Sql errorjava.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc, tomcat7

I have written a Java servlet program and run it through local Tomcat 7, But it was showing following error :

```
   Sql errorjava.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."PASSMANAGER"."PASS")
```

When i post values was not reading password.It showing password is null.

My source code is in following page :

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889694/the-requested-resource-is-not-available
```

If anyone know the solution please help me...........

Comment: hey have declared any primary key in ur database table. can use give ur db structure

Comment: Yes UNAME as primary key DB structure is UNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) No  1 
PASS VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) No  2 
EMAIL VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) Yes  3 
PHONE NUMBER No  4UNAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) No  1 
FNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) No  2 
LNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) No  3 
DOB DATE Yes  4 
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) No  5 
CITY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) Yes  6 
STATE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) No  7 
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) No  8 
PIN NUMBER No  9 
LANG VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) Yes  10   15 
GENDER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) No  16                     Sorry I cant add any more characters

Comment: I'm waiting for your reply please reply soon.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey correct your code in servlet .it will work

```
 password=req.getParameter("pass");
```